# Unable to create application on xampp server

Tags: windows, yii, xampp

Hi friends i am new to yii,i have download the yii folder and place that into

> C:\xampp\htdocs

this directory , when i try to create a application with the following command  `

> C:/xampp/htdocs/yii/framework/yiic webapp C:/xampp/htdocs/blog

` it is throwing the error 
can anybody tell me where i am doing a mistake

Comment: you should post the error message too, so people can help you

Comment: i am gettind   access s denied

Comment: Is access denied to the target directory? Does the ./blog directory exist? Does the process have write permission?

Comment: the above command should create the blog folder for a new app

Comment: "should" indeed. But it doesn't. Access is denied. The process can't create the blog directory. So the solution lies somewhere in your permission settings...

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step.

right click "my computer"
go to "system properties" under "advanced" tab, click on "environment variables"
under "system variables" find for the variable named "PATH" and click on "Edit" button

in "Variable Value" append the php.exe path with a semi-colon like below
;C:\xampp\php

cd c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework

yiic webapp ..\newapp